# Avoid recording errors and debug logs on CakePHP 2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, logging

I am using an small hosting with only 200Mb of space and the error.log and debug.log files placed in "App/tmp/logs" are increasing in size very fast. Now their size is around 120Mb.

I am using a cron job every 2 minutes and it could be the cause of it.

I would like to disable the creation of both logs. 
How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *actual* solution is to fix the errors and remove the debugging statements so that nothing would be written in the logs. To answer the question literally, you can [configure the error handler](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/errors.html#error-configuration) to not log anything in core.php:

```
Configure::write('Error', array(
    'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleError',
    'level' => 0,
    'trace' => false
));
```

Or, since you're running a cron job every 2 minutes anyway, delete the logs at the same time.

Comment: Ok, i think i will opt for your first solution:)
Thanks Juhana!! :)

Comment: Hey again Juhana. Now i have a problem, it works well but it gives this error when i have debug set to 2 in core.php
Use of undefined constant E_NONE - assumed 'E_NONE' in core.php on line 70

Also, Xdebug shows me the error.

Comment: Sorry, E_NONE doesn't exist (my bad). Use zero instead.